# Image carousel in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, carousel

I need an image carousel for my application (Angular v6). While surfing, I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857227/angular-4-image-sliders) which uses using `ngx-drag-scroll`. Is there any other way to do the image carousel like this  carousel and display the [card](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples) component inside it?

[image: Scroll]

Can it be achieved without using jQuery and only Typescript?

Comment: try UI-carousel https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-carousel

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[image: angular material card slider]

> Is there any other way to do the image carousel like this ?

Yes

> Without using jquery/javascript,using only Typescript - can I achieve this?

Yes (well TypeScript is a super set of JavaScript and you still need to interact with the DOM but yeah)

---

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slidercarousel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider%2Fslider.component.ts)** of a simple implementation that seems to behave, look and feel like your requirements. (For example you can pass it Material [`Card`](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples) components).

It basically works like this: you give the `SliderComponent` DOM Elements (`SliderItemDirectives`) and it will add the current most left Element's width to the scroll position of the slider container when you click right. Clicking left subtracts width. I have made use of `ContentChildren` and `ViewChild` to get to the widths and `scrollLeft` property. The animation is achieved with the css `scroll-behavior: smooth;`.

Here is the main Component:

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit, ContentChildren, ViewChild, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SliderItemDirective } from './slider-item.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(SliderItemDirective, { read: ElementRef }) items
    : QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>;
  @ViewChild('slides') slidesContainer: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  private slidesIndex = 0;

  get currentItem(): ElementRef<HTMLDivElement> {
    return this.items.find((item, index) => index === this.slidesIndex);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('items', this.items);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('slides', this.slidesContainer);
  }

  onClickLeft() {
    this.slidesContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= this.currentItem.nativeElement.offsetWidth;

    if (this.slidesIndex > 0) {
      this.slidesIndex--;
    } 
  }

  onClickRight() {
    this.slidesContainer.nativeElement.scrollLeft += this.currentItem.nativeElement.offsetWidth;

    if (this.slidesIndex < this.items.length - 1) {
      this.slidesIndex++
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions that would do what you need, here is the most simple one:

Structure your component something like this:

```
<component>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <card>
    <card>
    <card>
    ...
    <card>
  </div class="wrapper">
</component>
```

Use CSS to hide overflow on the x axis of the component, then programmatically add and subtract left margin on the wrapper when buttons are clicked.

You can use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get a hold of the wrapper in your component class so you can manipulate its' CSS values